# bash script cronjob not working

Tags: cron

Why is the cronjob below not working?
As manually executed script is working, but if I put it on cron job it doesn't push through.

```
#--------Reports-------------
25 11 * * * /logs/scripts/chim/currbalance_dump.sh >> /logs/currbal.log
```

script is below

```
#!/bin/bash

sftp sftpadm@203.177.165.92 << SFTP
cd /home/sftpadm/BanKo/CurrBalance/
mget banko_current_balance_`date +%Y%m%d`.csv /logs/Reports/BanKo/CurrBalance
SFTP
exit
```

Folder is

```
/logs/scripts/chim/currbalance_dump.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 kycadm kycadm 174 Sep 29 09:43 currbalance_dump.sh
```

Comment: What is `mget` and where is it installed ( `type mget` )

Comment: Even I don't know about `mget` but try to give the absolute path for `mget`

Comment: Add a `2>&1` at the end of the cron (after `>> /logs/currbal.log`), now the log should tell you where it is failing.

Comment: mget is a sftp specific command to download multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the read/write privilege to /etc/crontab file, then it should include username in the job line as follows:

```
crontab -l -u username

    25 11 * * * username /logs/scripts/chim/currbalance_dump.sh >> /logs/currbal.log
```

User specific cron job scripts can be found at /var/spool/cron/username

Also, make sure the bash script has executable bit set on it and the user executing the script has access to the directory /logs/scripts/chim/

```
 chmod +x currbalance_dump.sh
```

You can also put all your scripts in a directory and use the run-parts utility to execute all scripts in that directory

If everything above is ok, then check if the crond daemon is running or not

```
service crond status
service crond start
```

You don't need to restart the crond daemon every time when you write a new cron job.

Also, check the user is permitted to run a cron job

```
less /etc/cron.allow
less /etc/cron.deny
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check that selinux isn't the issue (as root):

```
audit2allow /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

Depending on the issue you can generate a policy to allow:

```
audit2allow -m local-log-script -o local-log-script.te /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

Edit that so it only has what you need for your script and then generate and import the selinux policy file:

```
checkmodule -M -m -o local-log-script.mod local-log-script.te
semodule_package -o local-log-script.pp -m local-log-script.mod
semodule -i local-log-script.pp
```

I usually store all those files in `/etc/selinux/custom/`